# how to use cellValueChanged event in datadrid view to use filter function?

Tags: c#

I write a function to filter datagridview(dgv)

```
void filterDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, string columnName, string filterValue)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[columnName].Value.ToString().Contains(filterValue))
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
        else row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I have 2 dgv with same column!
 . one of them is for searching in the secend dgv.
I write this function for dgv1.
first dgv has one row to write string in each column 
secend dgv contains data for searching.

please help me how can i use firs dgv ?-->(in each cell of dgv1 i write a string ,in dgv2 it be filter) how can i do that ? how can i set properties og dgv1 and what event will be helpful and how can i use it

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your DataGridViews are bound to a BindingSource why don't you use the `BindingSource.Filter` property instead of implementing your own filtration?

Comment: i don't bind dgv to binding source  i fill dgv myself.how could i set dgv properties to have only one row and user can write on cell ???

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to use your first `DataGridView` (having the same column as the second but one row only) to insert filter strings in it.

So what's wrong with a code like this (just an example):

```
this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

var colA = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col A", "Column A");
var colB = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col B", "Column B");

var rowIdx = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hello", "World");
this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowIdx].ReadOnly = false;


this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
```

Handling CellValueChanged event to trigger your filter:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var editedCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    var newValue = editedCell.Value;

    // apply filter here...
}
```

Comment: i knew how add columns but i couldn't type any thing in run time in dgv;I put read only property false for dgv but i cant write any thing in dgv1 on run time :(

Comment: If your code is exactly equal to mine, it should work. Have you tried to press F2 on a cell to start edit mode ?

Comment: i create a new project because that one didn't work. it work now :)

Comment: how can i ask grid view to know which cell is active and pass cell's value to my function ?is  cellvaluechanged event suitable for this ? how?

Comment: @sss: Yes, it is suitable. When you finish to edit the cell (by pressing ENTER or clicking out of the cell) the CellValueChanged event is called and you can retrieve the cell value as shown in my answer (edited)